# What is the faster way to access a DataTable/DataRowsCollection?

Tags: performance, datatable, dataset

I have a datatable with 100,000+ DataRow. Which method is faster to access the collection?
Is there any faster way to process the rows collection ?
Method 1:

```
var rows= dsDataSet.Tables["dtTableName"].Rows;
int rowCount = dsDataSet.Tables["dtTableName"].Rows.Count;

for (int c = 0; c < rowCount; c++)
{
    var theRow = rows[c];        
    //process the dataRow 
}
```

Method 2:

```
for (int c = 0; c < dsDataSet.Tables["dtTableName"].Rows.Count; c++)
{
    var theRow = dsDataSet.Tables["dtTableName"].Rows[c];
    //process the dataRow 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting the most direct way to access *cells* is via the `DataColumn` indexer; the data is actually stored in the columns, not the rows (no: really).

So something like:

```
var table = dataSet.Tables["dtTableName"];

// HERE: fetch the DataColumn of those you need, for example:
var idCol = table.Columns["Id"];
var nameCol = table.Columns["Name"];

// now loop
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    var id = (int)row[idCol];
    var name = (string)row[nameCol];
    // ...
}
```

However, frankly if you want the best performance, I would start by saying "don't use `DataSet` / `DataTable`". That is actually a very complicated model designed to be all kinds of flexible, with change tracking, rule enforcement, etc. If you want *fast*, I'd use a POCO and something like "dapper", for example:

```
public class Foo {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
...
string region = "North";
foreach(var row in conn.Query<Foo>("select * from [Foo] where Region = @region",
         new { region })) // <=== simple but correct parameterisation
{
    // TODO: do something with row.Id and row.Name, which are direct
    // properties of the Foo row returned
    var id = row.Id;
    var name = row.Name;
    // ...
}
```

or even skip the type via `dynamic`:

```
string region = "North";
foreach(var row in conn.Query("select * from [Foo] where Region = @region",
         new { region })) // ^^^ note no <Foo> here
{
    // here "row" is dynamic, but still works; not quite as direct as a
    // POCO object, though
    int id = row.Id;        // <=== note we can't use `var` here or the
    string name = row.Name; // variables would themselves be "dynamic"
    // ...
}
```

Comment: my goal is to have a faster access to the DataTable (well for now I cannot escape it). Can you enlighten further :) ? Is accessing datatable by columns marginally faster ?

Comment: @DioPhung than accessing them by name or by index? yes, marginally.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I don't see difference. I lose the same time to assignments for DataRows after switched from indexes to columns.